# Structure of MYSQL database table for visitor counter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, visitor-statistic

I have a userbase on db

```
______________________________________________
id | Name | so many details | Unique page link
______________________________________________
1  | abc  | bla bla         | username
```

So, user abc have a page `xyz.com/username`

I want to show user abc stats about visitors i.e. like 
1 jan - 400
2 jan - 350
and so on for last 7 day
and also the month wise record for last 12 months
jan - 49009
feb - 73849

what would be the best MYSQL database table structure design.

```
 _________________________________________________________________
    user id | day 1 | day2| and so on for 7 day | Jan | Feb | Mar
    ______________________________________________________________
    111111  |  400  | 300 |                     | 4250|24534|2435
```

I thought of something like this - is it OK or other optimized design is there?

Comment: Your question contains insufficient data, e.g where are the days. Please edit. Also, an example of the expected outcome with real numbers would be nice.

Comment: I got solution answered below.
I think question is quite clear and sufficient from my side and also the numbers are in the same format as given above. I only wanted to know best format which can be used for the visitor counting purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do it your way because you will have a long calender for each user.
It will get out of hand quickly.

You would want to have a table containing:

| ID | user_id | time_stamp | info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 324 | 2014/1/22 | 300 |
| 2 | 327 | 2014/1/20 | 500 |
| 3 | 324 | 2014/1/19 | 900 |

Than when you want the info.

```sql
Select * FROM table where user_id = 324
```

Would return

| ID | user_id | time_stamp | info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 324 | 2014/1/22 | 300 |
| 3 | 324 | 2014/1/19 | 900 |

Comment: I have a already running site with users having page view of about 4K-5K.
Would this method be ok and customized for my purpose as It will add thousands of rows daily.

Comment: yes, this will be the simplest way of keeping track.

Answer (score 2):

I would not keep a count in a database this way.

I would store records with timestamps as a column and roll them up using a GROUP BY every time I wanted them.

If this is a reporting database, I'd recommend looking into a star schema with a time dimension.

Answer (score 1):

aI think that something like this would be more easy to manage.

```
user_id
date
counter
```

For every visit check if the user is there for that date. if so increment, otherwise create record.
Then you can do as many stats as you want by using the date (day, month, interval etc.)